# How to turn off power/signal on a laptop HDMI port? (It triggers HDMI switch)

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, switch, htpc, dvr

I have a automatic/intelligent [HDMI switch](http://www.dx.com/p/3-port-1080p-hdmi-v1-3-mini-switch-3-in-1-out-36266#.VNSgA53F_YE) . Automatic in the way that it always switch to the latest input that receives signals.

I have connected a laptop (Windows 7, ati 4670 with official catalyst 10/15/2013 driver (latest available per today) in one input and a DVR (Tv-decoder) in another input, and the output to a projector.

The problem is that the DVR always send out HDMI signals, as it it don't get turned off with the power off button, its only set in standby mode. The pc also send out signals if it is in sleep mode. When pc or DVR is set in standby and then turned back on, the switch won't react as the HDMI port still send signals when its in standby/sleep.

Scenario:
I am using the pc and then turn on the DVR (to watch tv) the projector still will show pc screen. If I set pc in sleep, the projector goes black, but the HDMI switch is still set at the PC. If i disconnect the HDMI cable from the pc (or turn the pc off), the switch switches to DVR, and it shows on the projector. I don't want to shut the pc down to watch tv.

The question is, is there a program/software change that can force the HDMI port on the pc to stop send signals, so that the switch will switch from pc to DVR?

Info:

- Put pc in sleep mode - No reaction on the HDMI Switch
- Windows-key + p -> deactivate second display -  No reaction on the HDMI Switch
- Put pc in hibernate mode - Changes  to DVR
- Power off pc - Changes to DVR
- Unplug HDMI - Changes to DVR
- HDMIYO / [HDMIOn](http://thydzik.com/tag/hdmion/)   - The laptopscreen flashes, but no reaction on the HDMI Switch
- Tried search for options to disable hdmi in Windows Device Manager, but seems only possible to disable HDMI Sound, or to disable other ports like USB.

> Update 9.2.14:
>   Some more attempts added under info paragraph

Comment: A program?  No; The program would have to exist on the device itself for that to work.  But the simplest solution is getting yourself a better HDMI switch.  My HDMI switch allows me to cycle through the inputs, this allows the other devices to be left on, works great for devices that are kept on or in stand-by mode ( Xbox One, PS4, ect. )

Comment: Well, the HDMI switch has a button to press to cycle through the inputs, but it would be more convenient if it was possible  to  deactivate the hdmi port on the laptop and in that way get the switch to change to the DVR source..

Do you have a pc or a DVR/tv-decoder connected to your hdmi switch? Does it change automatically to correct source when the DVR is turned on?

Comment: Literally indicated what I have connected, yes, I have PC like devices and a HDDVR

Comment: Nice,do you know if your hdmi switch support port prioritization, maybe thats the reason it work? The "Switching Trouble" paragraph on [this page](http://www.macworld.com/article/1156810/hdmi_switches.html) says that hdmi switches usually got problems with devices in standby, without this version. Anyway, to get the switching work on my hdmi switch it would be nice deactivate the hdmi port on the pc, but its hard to know how, wish it had its own entry in the Device Manager like usb...

Comment: I don't normally suggest products [This](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=101&cp_id=10110&cs_id=1011002&p_id=7974&seq=1&format=2) is what I use.  I also bought cheap high quality HDMI cables.